# Elasticsearch5.6 : [reindex] failed to parse field [script]

Tags: elasticsearch

I read the Tutorial [to "Custom type field"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYWeb.png),
When I run this code:
[image: the code]

The error was reported：
[image: the error]

I hope someone can help me.thanks.

```
  [1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_parent_child_without_mapping_types
```

Comment: Try updating `source` in `script` to `inline`. see this: https://qbox.io/blog/reindex-documents-with-ease-without-third-party-scripts-using-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

I recently bumped into this, but my solution was a little different.

I believe the [ElasticSearch documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#_url_parameters_3) concerning scripting with `reindex` might be incorrect, or at least it did not work for me.

Instead of using `source` in the following:

```
"script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.foo == 'bar') {ctx._version++; ctx._source.remove('foo')}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
```

I had to use `inline`:

```
"script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.foo == 'bar') {ctx._version++; ctx._source.remove('foo')}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
```

And then, worked like a charm.  Checked with raw HTTP requests and python ElasticSearch client.  This was on ElasticSearch version 5.5.1.